# Ruby http Get returning truncated response

Tags: http, http-get, postman

I tried sending a HTTP Get to a device's Restful API via Postman and it worked fine returning all text I was expecting. Postman suggested Ruby code for the request was the following:

```
url = URI('http://192.168.1.5/rest/op/BD1FD3D893613E79')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request.basic_auth 'admin', 'admin'
request["accept"] = 'Application/json'
response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

but when I tried that in my code, it is returning a truncated response (missing lines) and I have to resend the same Get multiple times to get the entire text response response.

Is there anything missing in the Ruby code above that's causing this truncated response?

**Update 1**

I tried this

```
url = URI('http://192.168.1.5/rest/op/BD1FD3D893613E79')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request.basic_auth 'admin', 'admin'
request["accept"] = 'Application/json'
response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
response.read_body do |segment|
   puts segment.to_s
end
```

and that generated this error

```
IOError (Net::HTTPOK#read_body called twice):
```

**Update 2**

I tried this

```
1073 url = URI('http://192.168.1.5/rest/op/BD1FD3D893613E79')
1074 http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
1075 request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
1076 request.basic_auth 'admin', 'admin'
1077 request["accept"] = 'Application/json'
1078 response = http.request(request)
1079 response.read_body do |segment|
1080   puts segment.to_s
1081 end
```

and got this error

```
IOError (Net::HTTPOK#read_body called twice):
  app/controllers/Apps_controller.rb:1079:in `block in get_config'
  app/controllers/Apps_controller.rb:1045:in `each'
  app/controllers/Apps_controller.rb:1045:in `get_config'
```

Comment: Remove the line `puts response.read_body`

Comment: Thanks @Aguardientico for the follow up. I tried your suggestion as shown in Update 2, but still no luck

Comment: Are you trying to run both API and client in the same server instance? What server are you using?

Comment: @Aguardientico : thanks for the follow up. The client is my RoR App and the server is a 3rd party device. I don't know what server is running there. I just have the instructions to use their API, and it is working fine when I use Postman, but my App is failing as described above.

Comment: @rh4games - did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html#method-i-read_body

`read_body` returns the body as stream, so you should iterate it, something like:

```
response.read_body do |segment|
  puts segment
end
```

If you want to get the full body just use: `response.body`

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I replaced response.read_body with response.body but that did not change anything to my issue.

Comment: The only thing I can think is wrong is the missing `'` in your first line of code `url = URI('http://192.168.1.5/rest/op/BD1FD3D893613E79)` should be `url = URI('http://192.168.1.5/rest/op/BD1FD3D893613E79')`

Comment: Thanks @Aguardientico. I fixed that, but still no luck, and the code you proposed "response.read_body do |segment|
  puts segment
end" generates this error "IOError (Net::HTTPOK#read_body called twice):"

Comment: Yes, it generated this error "IOError (Net::HTTPOK#read_body called twice):"

Comment: can you update the question with the code that generates the error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks very similar....

We are getting truncated responses when pulling a set of artifacts (zip files) from a Bamboo server and writing to local storage.  It happens inconsistently, on only one of 8 servers, and not always the same file.  Seems always to be the last portion of the file that is missing.

Using Ruby 2.0.0p598 and net/http.

The zip files range in size from 2 mb to 34 mb.

While we haven't figured out why the response body has been truncated, our workaround is to compare the expected content length (in the response header), to the response body size. If they don't match, try it again.  Example code:

```
package = "packages/applicationname.zip"

def retrieve(package)

  # generates the Bamboo url for the given package
  sourceURL = package_url package

  expectedLength = 0
  bodyLength = 1

  #  Try to catch the bad download and re-issue the GET request,
  while expectedLength != bodyLength do

    # add a counter if worried about getting stuck

    # issue the request to get the current package zip file
    response = my_request_wrapper sourceURL

    expectedLength = response['content-length'].to_i
    theBody = response.body
    bodyLength = theBody.size

    if expectedLength != bodyLength then
        puts "!!  SIZE MISMATCH   !!"
    else
        # the response body is good, process as needed
        open package, 'wb' do |io|
          io.write theBody
        end
    end
  end
end

def my_request_wrapper(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  req.basic_auth("user", "pwd")
  return http.request req
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using OSX Sierra, rvm, and ruby 2.3.0

Updating my rvm, ruby, and gems seems to have fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you must call `http.start` before you call `http.request`.
Not sure why, but I see the same.